# how to show a series is not uniformly converges?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Well , this is the function sequence:$$f_k\left(x\right)\:=\:\frac{1}{k+k^2x}$$
I want to prove that there is **no** uniform convergence for $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{k+k^2x}$ , in ($0$,$\infty $).

I thought about show the **sequence** is not uniformly converge in ($0$,$\infty $) but i don't know how can i show it.
How can i do it?

Edit: the functions are all from ($0$,$\infty $) to R

Comment: you need to start the sum at k=1 so you aren't dividing by 0.

Comment: ok i edited this

Comment: Show that for any $N$, there is an $L$ so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0+}\sum_{k=N}^{N+L} f_k(x)$ is greater than $1$.

Comment: As a source of many examples, take just about any power series with infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: @DavidMitra I see u using Cauchy. so i started and i get $\left|\sum \:_{k=m+1}^{n\:}\:\frac{1}{k+k^2x}\right|\:<\left|\:\sum \:_{k=m+1}^n\:\frac{1}{k^2x}\right|$. what i need to do from here?

Comment: No, wrong approach. For any $L$, the limit above is $\sum_{k=N}^{N+L} {1\over k}$. This can be made as large as you wish by taking $L$ sufficiently large. In particular, this implies the series isn't uniformly Cauchy.

Comment: @DavidMitra sorry mate, i don't understan how to do it. can you explain yourself?

Comment: Given $N$, choose $L$ so that $\sum_{k=N}^{N+L} {1\over k}\ge 1$. From the limit condition, there is an $x\in(0,\infty)$ so that $\sum_{k=N}^L f_n(x)\ge {1\over2}\sum_{k=N}^{N+L} {1\over k}\ge 1/2$. (This is essentially the, more succinct, argument in the answer below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $n$

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+k^2x}>\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k+k^2x}>\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\frac{n}{2n+4n^2x}> \frac1{2},$$

so the convergence is not uniform on $(0,\infty)$