# How to show $\sum (-1)^n \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ is not uniformly convergent 0n $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

How can I show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^n \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$ is not uniformly convergent 0n $\mathbb{R}$.
I tried using Abel's test by taking $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ as convergent series and $\{\frac{x^2+n}{n}\}$ as monotone decreasing for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$. The problem is showing uniform boundedness of $\{\frac{x^2+n}{n}\}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
The sequence of function is uniformly bounded on any bounded interval but on the real line as $x$ has no bound so $\{\frac{x^2+n}{n}\}$ cannot be uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus Abel's test fails. Similarly for the Dirichlet's test.
Then I saw [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845923/how-to-show-a-series-is-not-uniformly-converges), i.e. using Cauchy sequence to show not uniformly convergent. But I failed to use that technique here.

Comment: You have already identified a problem with uniform boundedness. That's indeed the issue, or weaker version of the issue: If a series of functions converges uniformly, the individual functions converge uniformly to $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : so I needed only to show that $\{\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\}$ is not uniformly convergent to 0 in $\mathbb{R}$, which I think is true here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. For a given $N\geq 1$, what is
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\right|=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|A_N x^2+B_N\right|?$$
where $A_N=\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ and $B_N=\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Note that $A_N\not=0$.

Comment: As $A_N$ and $B_N$ are both bounded so here $\sup$ can be greater than any real number by suitably choosing $x$, thus violating Cauchy's condition for convergence. Do I catch your point?

Comment: @asimath $A_N\not=0$ suffices to say that that $\sup$ is $+\infty$. Note that the sup is with respect to $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

By contradiction, assume that the series is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$ then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\Vert R_n\Vert_\infty=0$$
where

$$R_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^2+k}{k^2}$$
so since 
$$R_n-R_{n-1}=(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$
we get
$$\Vert R_n\Vert_\infty+\Vert R_{n-1}\Vert_\infty\ge\Vert R_n-R_{n-1}\Vert_\infty=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\left\vert(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\right\vert=+\infty$$
which is a contradiction.